# SSL certificates without IIS in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh

I have been using GoDaddy to provide SSL security for some applications hosted by IIS; I've become familiar with the whole process that starts in IIS with generating the CSR and ends in IIS with completing the request and binding the certificate to the desired sites.

I am migrating applications from IIS to stand-alone Windows services (OWIN self-hosted), so I need to obtain a .pfx file I can bind to the appropriate port(s) using `netsh http add sslcert`... So far, I've obtained my .pfx files by following the IIS method and then exporting the certificate. It has the advantage of being relatively low-friction - the steps use tools/features already on the server (IIS), consist mostly of point/click (except for the final netsh port binding). But, this approach has the disadvantage of a dependency on IIS. I think I've seen some alternatives, but they seem to involve a lot of steps and the accompanying instructions were ambiguous.

I'm trying to find a straightforward, low-friction way to create a CSR for GoDaddy to sign and generate a corresponding netsh installable .pfx without any dependency on IIS. Is this possible, or is the IIS way the simplest/least friction?

Answer (score 0):

I use [XCA](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/index.php) for Linux, as my personal computer runs on Debian. You can download it for Windows if that OS is what you prefer. XCA is a very useful tool for certificates:

- It allows to run your own CA
- You can generate CSR for certificates  to be signed externally,
- You can sign with your CA certificate, CSR externally created.
- You can create and manage private keys.
- You can manage your certificates in order to export files in different formats, including p12 (.pfx).

I hope this can be of use for you.